# How do I update my EKS cluster after pushing a change to a Pod's ECR image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster running a service. After I've pushed a change to a Pod's ECR how can I get EKS to update the deployment with a new pod? So far I can only think of deleting the pod, forcing EKS to launch a new a new. Is there a better way of achieving this? I would like to have Jenkins force the pods recreation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a `kubectl -apply`? EKS will rotate old Containers, this is how it does rolling updates.

Comment: How does it know the container is old? Or maybe a better question, what does kubernetes consider an old container?

Comment: The simplest way is to `kubectl edit deployment/foo` to change to the newly built tag. Systems like flux can do this for you with its new image scanning.

Comment: But what if the tag hasn't changed? I was thinking of creating two images in my Jenkins pipeline. One will have the tag as the commit hash and the other will be "latest". Does it make more since to only make the unique tag instead of both?

Comment: There's a misconception about some used terms, update a cluster is different from updating a pod. Doesn't  exist Pod's ECR, there are Elastic Container Registry, pod is different from container, pod can have multiples containers. Take a time to read a little about kubernetes, there are a excellent documentation https://kubernetes.io

Comment: Yeap, engineers should use the right words. In this case, we still understand his question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend CI/CD here, after building your image, your CD will deploy it and Jenkins can take that role.

If the image tag hasn't changed, you can try with **kubectl rollout restart deployment deployment-name** (you may need this `imagePullPolicy: Always`).

If the image tag changes, you can use **sed** to replace it and run **kubectl apply**.

In my humble opinion, you should use `v1.Jenkins-build-number` or `v1.merge-request-number` ..., don't use `latest` for the image tag.